# what to do with a really large swapfile

Tags: swap

I have bought a new laptop.
It came with Ubuntu installed.
I have upgraded to 20.04.01 LTS.

In my root there is a really large swapfile, and that takes up a lot of space.
It's 137.6 GB and it's last altered on the 11th of september (more than a month ago).

I don't think i need this file, i have 64 GB of ram.
Is there a way to reduce the size?

output of `free` command

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       65613160     2528548    60546840       98704     2537772    62259952
Swap:     134217724           0   134217724
```

Comment: It is unlikely that you have that big a swap file and 120 GB of RAM in a laptop. It looks very weird. But you can remove or reduce your swap file. What does `free` command output?

Comment: sorry, i exaggerated if have 64 gb of ram. I have made an edit to the original message with the output of the free command. Can I safely lower the swap file to, say 8 GB?

Comment: You don't need a swap file if you have that much RAM.

Comment: ok. so can i safely delete the swapfile or do I need to de-register it first somewhere?

Comment: Remove it from `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the swap file totally with this amount of RAM.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo rm /swapfile
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and remove the line with the swap file from there.

Comment: thnx for this, this really helped